# Proving that there exist products of $a_k \equiv 1 \pmod {a_i}$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, congruences

> Let $n>2$ be an integer. Prove that there exist numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots ,a_n$ such that
>   $$a_1a_2\cdots \widehat{a_i}\cdots a_n \equiv  1 \pmod{a_i}$$
>   for $i=1,2,3,\ldots,n$. Here $\widehat{a_i}$ means that $a_i$ is omitted.

Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to math stackexchange.  It is expected that you include in your question your own thought/attempts at the problem.  Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: $a_1 = \ldots = a_n = 1$?